# get unique elements for given id from multiple columns in R

Tags: r

How to get unique elements for given id(foo) from multiple columns in R

```
df <- data.frame(
  foo = c("x1","x1","y1","y1"),
  c1 = c("apple","orange","banana","apple"),
  c2 = c("banana","apple","pear","grape"),
  c3 = c("orange","apple","banana","grape")
)

df
#>    foo     c1     c2     c3
#> 1:  x1  apple banana orange
#> 2:  x1 orange  apple  apple
#> 3:  y1 banana   pear banana
#> 4:  y1  apple  grape  grape
```

Desired

```
#> x1 apple banana orange
#> y1 apple grape pear banana
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two methods:

```
by(df[2:4], df$foo, function(a) unique(unlist(a, use.names=FALSE)))
# df$foo: x1
# [1] apple  orange banana
# Levels: apple banana orange grape pear
# ------------------------------------------------------------ 
# df$foo: y1
# [1] banana apple  pear   grape 
# Levels: apple banana orange grape pear
```

Or

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% tidyr::gather(k, v, -foo) %>% distinct(foo, v) %>% arrange(foo, v)
# Warning: attributes are not identical across measure variables;
# they will be dropped
#   foo      v
# 1  x1  apple
# 2  x1 banana
# 3  x1 orange
# 4  y1  apple
# 5  y1 banana
# 6  y1  grape
# 7  y1   pear
```

Comment: Can you pls tell why I get this warning with tidyr:
Warning message:
attributes are not identical across measure variables;
they will be dropped

Comment: Because your data is using `factor` instead of `character`. The premise of `factor`s is that there is a fixed known set of possible values. When you combine the columns into one, it is not perfectly obvious that it should (a) combine levels, (b) make all levels somehow distinct, or (c) perhaps convert into `character`. Since none of those are "safe", it does its best and drops some. Workarounds: (a) use `data.frame(..., stringsAsFactors=FALSE)` and same for `read.csv`; (b) use `as.character` after data is read/formed; or (c) manually use `levels(colname) <- all_levels` (vector of all levels).

Comment: Thanks. I added some more lines to form a table as output df %>% tidyr::gather(k, v, -foo) %>% distinct(foo, v) %>% mutate(x=c(as.factor(v))) %>% dcast(foo ~ x, value.var="v")

Answer (score 2):

Here is another `base R` option with `split`

```
lapply(split(as.matrix(df[-1]), df$foo), unique)
#$x1
#[1] "apple"  "orange" "banana"

#$y1
#[1] "banana" "apple"  "pear"   "grape"
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
   group_by(foo) %>%
   nest(.key = out) %>%
   mutate(out = map(out, ~ sort(unique(unlist(.)))))
```